FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/RMDS/CDA MEI 2022/ke12 Statistics Inference 2/datahouse_pricing.csv'
I have a problem to read my csv file from google colab, i stored my csv file at gdrive and copy that path as i use to read it and the csv file is found by list dir but it can't be open
enter image description here
please any one to solve my problem?
i try to re-upload the csv file to my gdrive and got still same error

Try with a / at the end if your path. Also you should include code, not an image. And maybe add tag python

awesome its worked and done.. i put / at the end.. thanks @Raphi for your suggestion
